# Missing Stream Events for Empty File Read inside Timeout

Tags: node.js

I'm working on code which reads from a file and includes timeout code. I'm having some issues with empty files.

Without the timeout, the below would print something like "readable:true, open, data (0+ times), end". This works the same with an empty file or a file with content. With the timeout (even of 0), the behavior varies drastically depending on if the file is empty. For a file with content, I get something like I did without the timeout, but with an empty file all I get is "readable: false".

Why does this work so different with empty files when I have a timeout (even of 0)? Is there an easy workaround for this issue?

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileNameTarget);
stream.pause();
setTimeout(function() {
  stream.resume()
  console.log('readable: ' + stream.readable);
  stream.on('open', function() {
    console.log('open');
  });
  stream.on('data', function() {
    console.log('data');
  });
  stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end');
  });
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `setTimeout` yields control to node event loop.

This means that while without `setTimeout` control doesn't leave your code until stream event handlers are all set up, in the version with `setTimeout` following can happen:

1. You start reading the stream at `var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileNameTarget);`
2. Control is immediately yield to node event loop with `setTimeout`
3. `'open'`, `'data'` and `'end'` events are triggered, but handlers aren't yet set up (since the `setTimeout` callback didn't take his turn to execute yet).
4. `setTimeout` callback executes, but the file has been read already.

File with content is slower to read and open, hence you get the same behavior as without `setTimeout` - the stream events all happen after the timeout event.

Comment: I added a pause and resume which I thought would prevent me from losing events. I'm still getting similar output. Is this expected?

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft that is strange.

Comment: @fmsf stream.pause() only pauses stream event emitting, not the whole runtime

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft mystery solved! `stream.pause()` only pauses emitting `'data'` events. So `'open'` will be unaffected by pause. You're not getting `stream.readable == false` in this case, are you?

Comment: I realized pause() only paused event emitting - I was hoping to prevent end from being emitted! Does it really still emit end even with pause state? To answer your question, with pause added I sometimes DO get readable: false, other times I get stream.readable == true and an open and end event. Some kind of timing thing. Ideas?

Comment: I'd say so. The stream is read on lower level even if the event emitting is paused - the events are buffered then. Once the event emitting is resumed the stream is no longer readable and all the buffered events are emitted.